# lagom microservices+maven module versioning

Tags: maven, git-submodules, lagom

When installing the scaffolding with Maven, there is a pom file for every module. Every module has a version that refers to the version of the parent project.
Is it overall good practice to link these versions? It basically means that for every change in one of the modules, a version update in the parent is required.

**I have two related questions to this:**

1. Is it good practice to use git submodules to manage vcs?
   I would expect that these modules can be run independently, but then again there seems overall promotion to always run (and deploy?) all microservices as a whole *(I might be wrong)*.
2. How do I manage URL API versioning with this? Let's say I want to update my post-api version, but not the one for my user-api. In the current situation, both API's will have the same current version (the one of the parent).
   I would expect the project (release) version of the pom file to correspond to the API version and would like to declare it in the path of the URL `api/1.0.0/...`. What is the right way to do so, or do you discourage this practice in general with Lagom microservices?

*Many thanks again for the help and sorry for the many questions.

I hope that this will help other users in the future too.*

Answer (score 0):

From what information I could gather and the logic I could think of:

1) If I understand it right, our VCS tracks the entire tree of related services that makes up our application. A version upgrade to the version of one service results in an upgrade of the entire system (the parent version). It is therefore possible to roll back the entire application to the latest stable release in case of errors.
From an operational point of view we can build / deploy / run services in bulk or individually. It is hence still possible to pick and choose specific past versions for certain services and deploy them as needed.
Regression testing in different environments (or using the sandbox in case of Conductr) is important because mistakes can happen when we don't manage our dependency graph correctly (e.g. forget to deploy a service that has a dependency on another service that was modified). I assume that we don't always want to redeploy all services for every change.
In terms of development we don't need to use git submodules if we commit our cross-service changes on separate branches per feature and deploy our branch to dev environment to test before merging to DEV branch or releasing. I don't see immediate problems happening here when working in team.

2) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lagom-framework/_2zFx3OBH7c/uZnFSXWoAwAJ:

Forward compatible api design is encouraged. In case of breaking changes, create a new version of the service and a 'bridging' service. It seems that we don't apply api versioning here (neither for internal or external exposure).
This raises some concerns for me, perhaps I didn't get it all right... Since we control our clients, it could work. Bridging services worries me a bit as I don't know the consequences when going down this road. When we control the system from client to server, I assume that most possible incompatibilities have been resolved after a few stable releases so I guess it won't be much of a problem.

Feedback or alternate answer welcome in case you disagree.